# How to fix: Error message in TestNG java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities.is(Ljava/lang/String;)Z

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenium-server

How to solve the following error message

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities.is(Ljava/lang/String;)Z in
>   automation project with Java, Selenium Server (having the
>   configuration : client-combined-3.7.1-sources, client-combined-3.7.1,
>   commo ns-lang-2.6,  org.eclipse.jgit_4.5.0.201609210915-r, 
>   selenium-firefox-driver-3.0.0-beta1,  selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1
>   firefox v. 44)

I have tried many combinations of selenium server & selenium Firefox driver but I was receiving other errors

```
<dependencies> 
  <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId> 
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId> 
    <version>6.8.8</version> 
    <scope>test</scope> 
  </dependency> 
  <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> 
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId> 
    <version>3.7.1</version> 
  </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

Only these lines of code I am using:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Aila\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win32\\geck‌​odriver.exe"); 
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Could you show in the question an XML of maven configuration of your project ? Especially `dependencies` section.

Comment: <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   <version>6.8.8</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>3.7.1</version>
  </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Comment: anyway I am not running the tests from pom files I am just running using Run as TestNG

Comment: You are using `selenium-firefox-driver-3.0.0-beta` from september 2016 (older than 1 year), while the nevest version is: [Selenium Firefox Driver  3.7.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/3.7.1)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I added it but I am having the same error.

Comment: Could you also share a java code you are using to instatiate the driver ? Dou you use FirefoxDriver, RemoteDriver ? Since the error message suggest some issue in `MutableCapabilities` class, please also show how do you pass capabilities to the driver. Thank You.

Comment: I don't use any capabilities. Only these lines of code I am usingSystem.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Aila\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
  driver = new FirefoxDriver();                                                                  Thanks

Comment: OK, then please run `C:\\Users\\Aila\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win32\\geck‌​odriver.exe` from the command line (just click on geck‌​odriver.exe file). A black window will appear with a version number of the driver, please post this version number here, thank you.

Comment: geckodriver 0.19.1

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities.is(Ljava/lang/String;)Z in automation project with Java, Selenium Server (having the configuration : client-combined-3.7.1-sources, client-combined-3.7.1, commo ns-lang-2.6, org.eclipse.jgit_4.5.0.201609210915-r, selenium-firefox-driver-3.0.0-beta1, selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1
```

First of all ensure that you are using all the binaries and jars of latest version (*Selenium*, *GeckoDriver*, *Firefox Browser*).

---

If you want to use ***Maven*** :

- Remove all the *Selenium* related jars which you have added manually from your project.
- Use *Selenium* and *TestNG* related jars only through ***Maven Dependencies***.
- Clean the *Project*
- Execute `mvn clean install test`

---

If you want to use *Selenium* and *TestNG* without ***Maven***:

- Remove all the *Selenium* related jars once and add only the  *`selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1`* within your project.
- Clean the Project
- Execute your *@Test* as ***TestNG Test*** or ***TestNG Suite***

Comment: Thank you for your answer but seems that everything I do I am facing the same error. I have the following jars: selenium 3.7.1, webdriver 1.6.2, testng 11.6. I did clean project, mvn clean install test; and still the same error is displayed

Comment: Now I am facing another error absolutely weird   Cannot find class in classpath: Tests.CreateDeviceTest
 at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
 at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
 at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
 at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:582)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)

Comment: My recent error when I do a mvn build is: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project RegAutoProject: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Aila/workspace/my/src/main/java/DEWA/ScheduledReportsUsagePatternsChargeCycles.java:[101,83] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Aila/workspace/my/src/main/java/DEWA/ScheduledReportsUsagePatternsChargeCycles.java:[179,83] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8

Comment: mvn clean, mvn install, mvn build and mvn test are working, but when I am running as TestNG the error I am receiving is: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.is(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.init(RemoteWebDriver.java:170)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:123)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution for this isssue:

1. Adding correct version in Selenium project coz different version don't have same solution for my issue selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar is correct.
2. This one is optional just try, if any of solution of this issue is not resolve.

Open Windows Command Prompt and type the command below:
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\NewAutomationCICD\resource\chromedriver.exe" -jar C:\NewAutomationCICD\libs\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar