# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions does not define error using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ShootingStrategies {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\SP00780555\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
}
```

At first it has run successfully, but after some time it started showing this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract boolean is(java.lang.String)' of interface org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities.
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.init(RemoteWebDriver.java:176)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:112)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
at ShootingStrategies.main(ShootingStrategies.java:7)
```

I'm using intellij Can some one help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract boolean is(java.lang.String)' of interface org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities.
```

......implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v95.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/95.0.4638.69/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 95.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v95.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/95.0.4638.69/notes.txt)).
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to fix: Error message in TestNG java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities.is(Ljava/lang/String;)Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47247925/how-to-fix-error-message-in-testng-java-lang-abstractmethoderror-org-openqa-se)